# Plex Media Server: bind: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, plex

I've been trying to install Plex Media Server following [this guide](http://www.htpcguides.com/install-plex-media-server-raspberry-pi-3-image/).

When I `source` `/etc/default/plexmediaserver` then:

```
start-stop-daemon --start -c $PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_USER --exec /usr/sbin/start_pms
```

(manually doing the steps the service file `/etc/init/plexmediaserver.conf` defines) I get:

```
6 3000 /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support
8192
Error: Unable to set up server: bind: Cannot assign requested address (N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_6system12system_errorEEEEE)
```

This problem persists through a reboot. The logs in `/var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Logs` look clean, besides also reporting the same cryptic error. The `Crash Reports` folder contains an empty folder structure.

I have reconfigured the package following [the uninstallation instructions](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/201941078-Uninstall-Plex-Media-Server):

```
dpkg -r plexmediaserver
rm -rf /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/
```

Then reinstalled:

```
sudo apt-get install -t jessie plexmediaserver
```

I had gotten Plex working previously, then this problem appeared and I reimaged the entire OS and tried again on a fresh install. This time, the server worked for a few minutes before a reboot then couldn't come back.

I'm really frustrated and would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this? https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/51427/plex-media-server-for-debian/p30 Sounds just like your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue after disabling ipv6 on my RPi 3. You have probably disabled ipv6 on your pi and Plex is trying to bind to it.

Go to:

```
/var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application\ Support/Plex\ Media\ Server/Preferences.xml
```

Then Change `EnableIPv6="1"` to `EnableIPv6="0"`

Restart your plex service and everything should be up and running.

Comment: I ran into this issue when I switched from running Plex in Docker to using Docker Compose. This fixed it.